# How to mock element by class in ElementRef in jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have added a clx element in component.ts file.

how to handle this `clx` element in jasmine.

```
export class defaultoComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit{
  el; timer;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      const colorData= document.getElementById('colorBed');
      const clx = this.el.querySelector('.clx');
      if (clx?.focus && !colorData) {
        clx.focus();
        clearInterval(this.timer);
      }
    }, 30);
  }
```

I have added like  but it is not pass for unit test for `clx` section

```
it('check afterviewinit', async () => {
    const element = document.createElement('div');
    document.getElementById = jasmine.createSpy('HTML Element').and.returnValue(mockedDocElement);
    spyOn(document.getElementById('colorBed'), 'focus');
    const clxelem= e1.nativeElement(By.css('.clx'));
    component.ngAfterViewInit();
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

Can any one help me please.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you just need to mock the `querySelector` method

```
it('check afterviewinit', async () => {
      spyOn(component.el, 'querySelector').and.returnValue({focus:() => false});
      component.ngAfterViewInit();
      expect(component.el.querySelector).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Comment: it is giving error, "Error: Expected spy querySelector to have been called."

Comment: can any one help on that issue,

Comment: can you show some code about how `el` is initialized ?